# Can't paste Image from Clipboard to RichTextBox

Tags: c#, image, winforms, clipboard

I'm looking to programmatically convert a base64 string into an Image that I then insert into a richTextBox.

Right now I load the string into a stream and convert that into an Image. I then load that onto the Clipboard and attempt to paste. However, when I execute the code, nothing pastes into the richTextBox. After running the code, the image is properly set in my Clipboard and I am able to paste it manually into the richTextBox - it just doesn't seem to work programmatically.

Here's my code:

```
byte[] img_bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imgStr);
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(img_bytes, 0, img_bytes.Length))
{
    Image img = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
    Bitmap imgb = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(img);
    Console.WriteLine(Clipboard.ContainsImage()); // Prints True
    richTextBox1.Paste(DataFormats.GetFormat(DataFormats.Bitmap));
    Console.WriteLine(richTextBox1.CanPaste(DataFormats.GetFormat(DataFormats.Bitmap))); // Prints True
    richTextBox1.Text += "\n";
}
```

Update: It appears that setting the text field after pasting the image deletes the image. I guess the question now is, how do I have both the image and the text?

Comment: Can you try to paste a non-streamed bitmap first? `richTextBox1.Paste(DataFormats.GetFormat(DataFormats.Bitmap));` strongly resembles the [msdn code example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/23kah9ca(v=vs.110).aspx) so I doubt there is a problem, but maybe your Bitmap is not working for any reason

Comment: I appear to be having the same problem - I loaded a PNG file from file but it fails to paste when I execute the program. The PNG does copy to my clipboard successfully and I am able to manually paste it into the richTextBox though :(

Comment: can you try to reproduce the whole code from msdn I linked before? Maybe the problem is somewhere else...

Comment: I found the problem! Setting the text after pasting the image deletes the image for some reason. Now to figure out how to have both the image and text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that setting a richTextBox's text attribute after pasting was deleting the image. I changed the line

```
richTextBox1.Text += "\n";
```

to

```
Clipboard.SetText("\n");
richTextBox1.Paste();
```

which is a pretty terrible solution but it works and I'm on a deadline :) I'm open to other suggestions that are less hacky!

Comment: Assigning data to `Text` replaces the RichTextBox's content by the original content, _as string_, plus the given string. You'd have to get to the RichTextBox's original underlying RTF data somehow.